# Readonly form fields

Tags: php, html, readonly

So I have an PHP file that includes a form so that users can post jobs on my website. I want to make some fields of this form ReadOnly to the user. How?

```
    public static function init_fields() {
    if ( self::$fields )
        return;

    self::$fields = apply_filters( 'submit_job_form_fields', array(
        'job' => array(
            'job_category' => array(
                'label'       => __( 'Job category', 'job_manager' ),
                'type'        => 'select',
                'required'    => true,
                'options'     => self::job_categories(),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'priority'    => 3
            ),
            'job_description' => array(
                'label'       => __( 'Description', 'job_manager' ),
                'type'        => 'text',
                'required'    => true,
                'placeholder' => '',
                'priority'    => 4
            ),
```

I know this is probably easy to do, but for some reason I can't find how to do it.

Comment: I tend to think there isn't enough info here to go off of. There is no php function `apply_filters()` for example. Is this WordPress or some other framework? BTW, I think you're looking for the resulting `<html>` `<input>`s to have the `disabled` attribute

Comment: Is this from a framework?

Answer (score 2):

Use the disabled attribute:

```
'job_description' => array(
                'label'       => __( 'Description', 'job_manager' ),
                'type'        => 'text',
                'required'    => true,
                'placeholder' => '',
                'priority'    => 4,
                'disabled'    => 'true' //html disabled input
            )
```

Comment: That could break the form, since it won't submit data (IIRC)

Comment: He could provide 2 versions of those fields, with one `disabled` and one `hidden` (and therefore active?)

Comment: PS, @AustinAllover, is this confirmed as being WordPress-specific (or if otherwise, do you know what framework)? I'd like to update the question Tags if so

Answer (score 0):

This is a proprietary config file.  You need to look at the code that is parsing it and converting to HTML.  It may allow passing through variables like `readonly`, or may not.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing 'readonly' => true in your array.

Remember that someone can change the value of the readonly field using an inspector like Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools, etc.